# How to minimize loop with if statement

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to minimize this piece of code

```
public static void UnfavSong(Song song)
{
    List<string> favorites = FileManagement.GetFileContent_List(FAVS_FILENAME);

    foreach (string s in favorites)
    {
        Song deser = SongSerializer.Deserialize(s);
        if (deser.ID == song.ID)
        {
            favorites.Remove(s);
            break;
        }
    }

    FileManagement.SaveFile(FAVS_FILENAME, favorites);
}
```

But I feel like the whole `foreach` part can be made much shorter.
Is there a way in C# to cut this down to the core?

Comment: Using linq, you can minimize a foreach loop.  But, it's generally a bad idea to modify a list (e.g. remove items from a list) while iterating over it.

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ

```
favorites.RemoveAll(s => SongSerializer.Deserialize(s).ID == song.ID)
```

Btw. your code shouldn't work at all as you can't modify the List during it's iteration

Answer (score 2):

you can use linq `Where()` to filter them:

```
List<string> result = favorites.Where(x=>SongSerializer.Deserialize(x).ID != song.ID).ToList();
```

This will give you all element except with the matching `ID` with `song.ID`